# How can I get the audio bitrate from a video file using FFprobe?

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I have a video and I'm looking to get the duration of the video, and the audio bitrate.

Using this script (which takes the video path as the first argument), I can get the duration and assign it to a variable.

```
videoSeconds=$(ffprobe -v error -show_entries format=duration -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 "$1")
```

However I'm not sure how to get the audio bitrate assigned to a variable (I've looked at the man page with no luck).

When I run `ffprobe` without any options I can see the audio bitrate as part of the wider information.

```
Side data:
  displaymatrix: rotation of -90.00 degrees
Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, mono, fltp, 96 kb/s (default)
Metadata:
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using this command, the key is using `-select_streams a:0 -show_entries stream=bit_rate`:

```
audioBitrate=$(ffprobe -v error -select_streams a:0 -show_entries stream=bit_rate -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 "$1")
```

Answer (score 9):

You can get it cleanly from ffprobe directly using,

```
ffprobe -v 0 -select_streams a:0 -show_entries stream=bit_rate -of compact=p=0:nk=1 "$1"
```

Comment: Thanks, Gyan! For anyone reading, this answer also worked for me, but I can only choose one correct answer.